# Are there any resources for simulating the Kuramoto model/solving the system of coupled ODEs for the oscillators?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations, complex-systems

I want to simulate the Kuramoto model and I am following a review by Strogatz to read up the theory. Are there resources that explain how to simulate the model and solve the coupled ODEs, or the mean field uncoupled ODE, numerically?

Comment: Have you looked at this package? https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering
It's linked directly in the Wikipedia page on the Kuramoto model (I've never used it so I don't know if it works)

Comment: Is this physics or a programming question?